# Delete consecutive duplicates

Tags: excel, vba, row

I want to delete consecutive duplicates but not consecutive blank rows, but it is deleting consecutive blanks cells as well. Here is my code:

```
Sub Dupl()

    Dim i As Long
    Dim y As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        For i = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row To 3 Step -1
            If .Cells(i, 1).Value = .Cells(i - 1, 1).Value Then
                If .Cells(i, 1).Value = " " Then
                    GoTo y
                End If
                .Rows(i).Delete
y:
            End If
        Next i
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Add another `IF` statement or include a `AND` statement

Comment: " " is a space. "" is blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the `IsEmpty()` function to check whether a cell is empty or contains a value. A space is considered a value.

```
    For i = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row To 3 Step -1
        If .Cells(i, 1).Value = .Cells(i - 1, 1).Value Then
            If Not IsEmpty(.Cells(i, 1).Value) Then
                .Rows(i).Delete
            End If
        End If
    Next i
```